# Policy that only allows to list a subset of roles

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I am using Vault's SSH PKI secrets engine and have multiple roles defined

```
pki/
   role1
   role2
   role3
   ...
```

I want to give access to the roles via web GUI. So for my understanding I have to specify a list policy:

```
   path "/ssh/*" {
       capabilities = ["list"]
   }
```

A user assigned with this policy can view all configured roles behind `/ssh/`. Is there a way such that a policy only allows to view a subset, lets say `role1`?

I checked the documentation about policies and could not really find anything. I also tried

```
   path "/ssh/role1" {
       capabilities = ["list"]
   }
```

which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The permission should be:

```
 path "/<pki-engine-path>/roles" {
       capabilities = ["list"]
   }
```

Default:

```
 path "/pki/roles" {
       capabilities = ["list"]
   }
```